# Obtain results from sql query only when apply function to field. Is it a bug of Poco::Data?

Tags: sqlite, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco::Data (version 1.8.1) to query a sqlite database (version 3.27) compiling with gcc version 7.3.0 for an onion omega2 (mips) running openwrt 18.06.
I have a strange behaviour.
When I execute a query like

```sql
select <real field> from ...
```

I've got a "NotFound" exception (query from command line returns a result, of course).
If I apply a function to it like "avg", for example, I have the correct result.
It doesn't happen with an integer field.
The field name is "psi": I think it is not a reserved word.
Is it a bug of Poco::Data? Is it something I'm doing wrong?

The code I'm using is:

```cpp
double result;
std::string query = "select <field> from table where <condition on pk>";
session << query, into(result), now;
```

this code gives NotFound.

Changing string query to:

```
std::string query = "select avg(<field>) from table where <condition on pk>";
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your query returns more than one result row. In that case, `into(result)` will fail if `result` is a scalar value. Try adding a `limit(0, 1)`, as in:

```
session << query, into(result), limit(1), now;
```

to only return a single result row.
This may not be what you want, however, as you'll basically get a random result row that matches your query. If you want all, you can use a vector for receiving the result, as in:

```
std::vector<double> result;
session << query, into(result), now;
```

There are also other options for obtaining a multi-row result, e.g. stepping through all result rows by executing the statement multiple times or using a `RecordSet`. See the [Binding](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/Data/samples/Binding/src/Binding.cpp) and [RecordSet](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/master/Data/samples/RecordSet/src/RecordSet.cpp) samples for the details.

Comment: No, the problem is somewhere else. The queries I'm using are on primary keys therefore they return always a scalar value, and it works well if I use a function like "cast" (for example cast(field as double)). I suppose it is a problem with how Poco::Data handles "real" datatype. Running a simple query like "select * from <table>", if <table> contains fields of "real" datatype the call gives "notfound" exception. Obviously, if I run the queries on command line all works fine.

Comment: Check whether the datatype of the column is actually "REAL". `Poco::Data::SQLite` has a fixed set of supported type names, check [Utility.cpp](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.9.0/Data/SQLite/src/Utility.cpp) for a list.